# Using \hyphenation and umlauts

Tags: errors, hyphenation

I have included the `ngerman` package and I write

```
\hyphenation{An-fangs-n"a-he-rung}
```

into the preamble of my document. However, latex complains with

```
!Improper \hyphenation will be flushed.
\grmn@OTumplayt ->\protect
                           \newumlaut
l.3 \hyphenation{An-fangs-n"a
                             -he-rung}
?
```

How can I fix this? By the way: I'm using the document class `scrartcl`.

**EDIT:** The following minimal not-working example leads to this error message:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\hyphenation{An-fangs-n"a-he-rung}
\begin{document}
Es soll das Wort names Anfangsn"aherung richtig getrennt werden. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I will do that.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no solution. Have a look for example here:
http://www.forkosh.com/latex/ltx-244.html

Comment: @bene hyphenation should just work, see the answers posted.

Comment: Instead of the obsolete `ngerman` package it's better to load `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to enable an encoding that has the accented letters, then that word appears to be hyphenated as you wish already using the default hyphenation patterns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}

%\hyphenation{An-fangs-n"a-he-rung}

\begin{document}


\parbox{2pt}{\hspace*{1pt}Anfangsn"aherung richtig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` exactly do? In my viewer the text look just slightly different now. But that might just be a rendering thing.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky It tells LaTeX to use an 8-bit "T1" encoded font family (these are in fact different fonts) in the classic Computer Modern fonts by Knuth there were only base letters and all accents are constructed using the `\accent` primitive you can not use such constructs in hyphenation patterns. there are several implementations now of "larger" computer modern fonts, you could add `\usepackage{lmodern}` for example to try the `lmodern` set.

Answer (score 15):

With the following MWE it should work. On my current MikTeX 2.9 it compiles without an error.

I used package `babel` with option `ngerman` and added the font encoding and input encoding. As you can see can you now write umlauts in the LaTeX document without shortcuts like `\"a` or `"a`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\hyphenation{An-fangs-nä-he-rung}
\begin{document}
Es soll das Wort namens Anfangsnäherung richtig getrennt werden. 
\end{document}
```

Because package `ngerman` is rather old (1998, see documentation on [`CTAN`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ngerman)) you should better use the maintained package [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) with option `ngerman` (latest document version 2012).

Please have a look on [english `l2tabu.pdf`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) or [german `l2tabu.pdf`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf) (the german version is newer) for outdated and obsolete packages you should not use longer (but you will still find them in older LaTeX documents ...).

Comment: Oh you just beat me to it:-)  In fact `\hyphenation` appears not to be needed in this case, the default hyphenation pattern gives the same hyphenation points.